# Classes with synchronized attributes

Tags: python

I am trying to create 2 classes, whose instances will have synchronized attributes, pointing to each other.

For example, given 2 classes `Item` and `Queue`:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, id, question, answer, queue=None):
        self.id = id

        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer

        self.queue = queue

class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = []
```

I want to make sure `item.queue` has the `item` inside it's `list`.

This is my attempt:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, id, question, answer, queue=None):
        self.id = id

        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer

        self.queue = None
        self.move_to(queue)

    def move_to(self, queue):
        if self.queue == queue:
            return

        if self.queue:
            self.queue.remove(self)

        self.queue = queue

        if self.queue:
            self.queue.add(self)

class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = []

    def add(self, item):
        if item not in self.list:
            self.list.append(item)
            item.move_to(self)

    def remove(self, item):
        if item in self.list:
            self.list.remove(item)
            item.move_to(None)
```

But I don't feel at ease with this solution. When I call `item.move_to`, `queue.add` will be called, which will in turn call `item.move_to` again, only to return because it's `queue` is already set.

Is this pythonic, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should an item *care* what queue it's in?  More importantly, why is an item responsible for it's movement between queue's?  Why not do this:

```
class Queue(object):
  def move_item_to_other_queue(self, item, other):
    if item in self.list:
      self.list.remove(item)
      other.list.append(item)
```

Comment: I guess I was just overcomplicating, like always. Though, I liked the way `item.move_to` looks. Anyways, the item has the queue attribute to make it easy to find out where it is: `item.queue`, as opposed to searching the queue. I could use another `dict` for that, but it doesn't look as good. I guess I was going too much for the syntax sweetness..